# Creating multiple canvas patterns fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to create an array of patterns to use for my [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org) doughnut chart so I do this:

```
var surfacePatterns
var surfaceNames = ['Unknown', 'Paved', 'Unpaved', 'Concrete', 'Cobblestone', 'Metal', 'Wood', 'Ground', 'Sand', 'Grass']

$(document).ready(() => {    
    surfacePatterns = []
    console.log(surfacePatterns)
    for (i = 0; i < surfaceNames.length; i++) {
        var temp = new Image()
        temp.onload = () => surfacePatterns.push($("#canvas1")[0].getContext('2d').createPattern(temp, 'repeat'))
        temp.src = '../img/surfaces/'+ surfaceNames[i] + '.jpg'
    }
});

function chart(){
   console.log(surfacePatterns)
}
```

The `chart()` function is called by a button press. I deliberately wait for a few seconds so it can load the images and create the patterns but when I call the function it gives me this:

[image: console]

Out of the nine images, only 8 and 9 got converted into a pattern and the rest is null. I have no idea what's going on because I get no errors and all images are found. If I change a String in `surfaceNames` I, as expected, get an error that an image couldn't be found and if I use patterns 8 and 9 they work perfectly fine.

Another weird thing: If I change

```
temp.onload = () => surfacePatterns.push($("#canvas1")[0].getContext('2d').createPattern(temp, 'repeat'))
```

to

```
temp.onload = () => surfacePatterns[i] = canvas1[0].getContext('2d').createPattern(temp, 'repeat')
```

The entire array is entirely empty (=/= null). Also, the first log after initializing the array as an empty array gives me an empty array with a length of 9 and I have no idea why since nothing else has happened yet.

Comment: To test: What if instead of the `surfacePatterns.push` you put a `console.log` do you get all 9 patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for all of the patterns to load before you can log the array. In fact, the array should be the *result* of awaiting all the patterns, rather than a variable in the outer scope that you populate asynchronously. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1541563)

As for how to solve this, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) after converting each callback into a pending promise:

```js
const surfaceNames = ['stackoverflow.com', 'codegolf.stackexchange.com', 'superuser.com', 'codereview.stackexchange.com'];
const context = document.querySelector('#canvas1').getContext('2d');
const promises = surfaceNames.map(surfaceName =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(context.createPattern(image, 'repeat'));
    });
    image.addEventListener('error', () => {
      reject(new Error(`${surfaceName} failed to load ${image.src}`));
    });
    image.src = `https://${surfaceName}/favicon.ico`;
  }).catch(error => {
    // populating array with null entry and logging error
    // instead of ignoring all the other pending promises
    console.log(error.message);
    return null;
  })
);

Promise.all(promises).then(surfacePatterns => {
  console.log(surfacePatterns.map(pattern => pattern.constructor.name));
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

As you can see, each of these successfully resolves with a [`CanvasPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern).

Comment: That is such a smart way to do this! I also learned about the \`String${variable}String\`-thing which is awesome as well. Thanks!

Comment: @MiXT4PE that syntax is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) available since ECMAScript 2015

Answer (score 0):

When calling an async function several times in this case inside a "for", you have to wait for all the calls. If you don't wait they you lost some async calls and you got an empty array.

If you can put a snipped I'll try to fix that problem.

```js
window.surfacePatterns = [];
window.c = 0;
//window.surfaceNames = ['Unknown', 'Paved', 'Unpaved', 'Concrete', 'Cobblestone', 'Metal', 'Wood', 'Ground', 'Sand', 'Grass'];
window.surfaceNames = ["https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w1200-h630-c1200x630/upload/37/99/85/northern-pygmy-owl.jpg",
  "https://www.friendsofwehr.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Great-horned_Owl_RWD_at_CRC1transparent.jpg"
];

$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log('Step 1: ', window.surfacePatterns);
  for (i = 0; i < window.surfaceNames.length; i++) {
    var temp = new Image();
    temp.onload = function() {
      var my = $(".canvas1")[0].getContext('2d').createPattern(temp, 'repeat');
      console.log('Step inside async: ', my);
      window.surfacePatterns.push(my);
      window.c++;
      if (window.surfaceNames.length === c) {
        console.log('Complete async calls: ', window.surfacePatterns);
      }
    }
    //temp.src = '../img/surfaces/'+ window.surfaceNames[i] + '.jpg';
    temp.src = "https://www.friendsofwehr.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Great-horned_Owl_RWD_at_CRC1transparent.jpg"

  }
  console.log('Outside For: ', window.surfacePatterns);
});

function chart() {
  console.log(window.surfacePatterns);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas class="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: As said above even if I wait for a minute or so before I call chart it is the same result. Or do you mean if I start the next async-call it will drop the one before?

Comment: The for run faster than the async call (method onload). Which framework do you use? Have you ever use the promise?

Comment: No framework. I don't use Promises - how would they be used in this scenario?